# How to install AVG for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: antivirus

I have downloaded AVG free installer file(avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386.sh) from http://free.avg.com/in-en/download-free-all-product.

Please let me know how to install it on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: What is the command for 32 bit os?

Comment: what makes you feel you need antivirus ? See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dowload the [deb file](http://download.avgfree.com/filedir/inst/avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386.deb) for Ubuntu, and then, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to  where the file was downloaded, probably the Downloads folder, and run the command(s) below:

*Install ib32-libs if you are on 64-bit PC*

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

sudo dpkg -i avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32ncurses5 lib32z1
```